# How to get post author name by its ID inside a function?

Tags: author

i'm trying to get the author name using the "`the_author_meta`" function. After doing that I need to pass the value inside an array and return that with "json_encode".

Let me show:

```
$autor_id = $post->post_author;
$autor_name = the_author_meta('user_nicename', $autor_id);
echo $autor_name;
```

The `$autor_name` `echo` works fine but when i do the following code it returns null on my script:

...

```
$results['author'] = $autor_name;
$posts[] = $results;
}

return json_encode($posts);
```

it returns that: `"author":null`

How can i make it display the author name like: `"author":admin`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The echoing is already done by the_author_meta().

`echo $autor_name` does nothing.

Correct would be to use get_the_author_meta().

Comment: Hi Scribu, first thanks for your fast reply. I feel really stupid hehe. Anyway I did the echo using the following code:   $userid = $post->post_author;
  $userdata = get_userdata($userid); and then $userdata->user_nicename worked perfectly here too. But thanks a lot for the information